Deriving everything from Gauss Law
I have a doubt in electordynamics,
I was learning Electrodynamics (last major topic) ,
and I learned about Maxwell's Equation, which can explain everything in Electrodynamics (actually according to my book).
So, can we derive everything of electrostatics (for now) using just Gauss Law ...
I was able to derives Electric field due to a single particle using it ,
after that I think we can derive everything if we are able to show Superposition principle of Electric Field lines .
Is there is any way to do it ?
Or I am getting something wrong ?
Please help , any help will be appreciated..

Your question is not so well-defined, thus not sure whether the following can be considered and answer..
Anyhow, one can show the following:
The 'simplest' equations that satisfy

Superposition principle (basically meaning the set of equations must be linear).
Lorentz covariance (meaning all entities in the equations must transform as they should if frame of reference is changed).
A point source (in the rest frame) obeys Gauss law.
Electric charge is conserved
There is no magnetic charge

are the Maxwell equations.
The 'proof' is not that difficult, but you should be familiar with the covariant of formulation of the Maxwell equations, like $\partial_{\mu} F^{\mu\nu} = j^{\nu}$ from which e.g. follows that $F$ must be an antisymmetric tensorfield if electric charge is to be conserved.

My question is Maxwell equation unifies Electordynamics, so is there is any way to show electric field's  super position property
